# Approximate point spectrum of a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

> Let $H$ a Hilbert space and $T:H \to H$ a linear, continuous and normal operator. Then for every $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $\Vert x_n \Vert = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert Tx_n - \lambda x_n \Vert = 0,$$
>   what means basically $\sigma(T) \subseteq \sigma_{ap}(T)$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where exactly do I need the normality then?

Comment: @Yaddle I am a little late, but as it is a good question I'll answer it. If $T$ isn't normal, $T - \lambda I$ mustn't be. Therefore it must not hold that $\| T x \| = \| T^* x \|$ for all $x \in H$, which is used in the proof as sketched below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case where $\mathcal{N}(T-\lambda I)\ne \{0\}$ is covered. So assume $\mathcal{N}(T-\lambda I)=\{0\}$ and $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$. Because $T-\lambda I$ is normal, then
$$
           \|(T-\lambda I)x\|=\|(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)x\|,\;\;x\in H,
$$
which also implies that $\mathcal{N}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)=\{0\}$. Therefore,
$$
      \overline{\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)}=\mathcal{N}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)^{\perp}=\{0\}^{\perp}=H.
$$
If $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)$ is closed, then $T-\lambda I$ is bijective and closed, which forces $\lambda\in\rho(T)$ and gives a contradiction. Therefore, $T-\lambda I$ is injective with a dense, non-closed range and an unbounded
inverse on that range. Hence, there exists a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_n \}$ in the range of $T-\lambda I$ such that $y_n=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}x_n$ tends to $\infty$ in norm. Renormalizing the tail of this sequence gives a sequence of unit vectors $\{ z_n = \frac{1}{\|y_n\|}y_n \}$ in $H$ such that $(T-\lambda I)z_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I am not quite sure, how $\overline{\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)}=\mathcal{N}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)^{\perp}$ follows. Can you elaborate that?

Comment: @Yaddle : $M^{TT}=\overline{M}$ for a subspace. $y\in\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)^T$ iff $((T-\lambda I)x,y)$ for all $x$; equivalently, $(x,(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)y)=0$ for all $x$ or $(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)y=0$.

Comment: Is the following correct for the other direction, i.e. $\sigma_{\text{ap}}(T) \subset \sigma(T)$? *Let $\lambda \in \sigma_{\text{ap}}(T)$, then there exists a sequence of uni vectors $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathscr H$ such that $(T - \lambda) x_n \to 0$, as the norm is continuous. If $\lambda \in \rho(T)$, $T - \lambda$ is invertible, so $x_n \to (T - \lambda)^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0$, which is contradiction to $\| x_n \| = 1$ together with the continuity of the norm.*

Comment: Could you clarify why $(T-\lambda I)$ has unbounded inverse? I understand why the image is dense and non-closed, but I don't see how the unbounded-ness comes from. Thanks!

Comment: @eatfood : If the inverse were bounded with dense domain, then it would extend by continuity to a bounded operator, and that bounded operator would be the inverse of $T-\lambda I$.

Comment: ohhh, understand now. Thank you!